# Working with DirectXMath and D3DXMath

Tags: directxmath

Back in D3DXMath  we had ability  to  multiply, add  or  subtract  even  divide  vector  types,  which  were  D3DXVECTOR2, D3DXVECTOR3, D3DXVECTOR4 structures..... 
Now  in DirectXMath  incarnation  we have  XMFLOAT2, XMFLOAT3, XMFLOAT4 and  XMVECTOR.  If  i want  to  do  any  math operation  i  must  do conversion from XMFLOAT to XMVECTOR  either way  Visual Studio  is throwing  an error "There is no 
 user  defined  conversion".  Why  is that ?    Actually  it's a fact  that  in a new version(Windows 8.1, 10)  of DirectX  math library  vector  operation slightly   has  changed .  Am i  doing  something  wrong........... ?!

P.S.  Well for Matrices  there  are  another  question but  right now  lets  talk only on  vectors.   These  changes  is pushing  third party  developers  to create  their own Math library  and  they  had  done  it.....  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually explained in detail in the [DirectXMath Programmer's Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/pg-xnamath-getting-started) on MSDN:

> The XMVECTOR and XMMATRIX types are the work horses for the DirectXMath Library. Every operation consumes or produces data of these types. Working with them is key to using the library. However, since DirectXMath makes use of the SIMD instruction sets, these data types are subject to a number of restrictions. It is critical that you understand these restrictions if you want to make good use of the DirectXMath functions.
>
> You should think of XMVECTOR as a proxy for a SIMD hardware register, and XMMATRIX as a proxy for a logical grouping of four SIMD hardware registers. These types are annotated to indicate they require 16-byte alignment to work correctly. The compiler will automatically place them correctly on the stack when they are used as a local variable, or place them in the data segment when they are used as a global variable. With proper conventions, they can also be passed safely as parameters to a function (see Calling Conventions for details).
>
> Allocations from the heap, however, are more complicated. As such, you need to be careful whenever you use either XMVECTOR or XMMATRIX as a member of a class or structure to be allocated from the heap. On Windows x64, all heap allocations are 16-byte aligned, but for Windows x86, they are only 8-byte aligned. There are options for allocating structures from the heap with 16-byte alignment (see Properly Align Allocations). For C++ programs, you can use operator new/delete/new[]/delete[] overloads (either globally or class-specific) to enforce optimal alignment if desired.
>
> However, often it is easier and more compact to avoid using XMVECTOR or XMMATRIX directly in a class or structure. Instead, make use of the XMFLOAT3, XMFLOAT4, XMFLOAT4X3, XMFLOAT4X4, and so on, as members of your structure. Further, you can use the Vector Loading and Vector Storage functions to move the data efficiently into XMVECTOR or XMMATRIX local variables, perform computations, and store the results. There are also streaming functions (`XMVector3TransformStream`, `XMVector4TransformStream`, and so on) that efficiently operate directly on arrays of these data types.

By design, DirectXMath is encouraging you to write efficient, SIMD-friendly code. Loading or storing a vector is expensive, so you should try to work in a 'stream' model where you load data, work with it in-register a lot, then write the results.

That said, I totally get that the usage is a little complex for people new to SIMD math or DirectX in general, and is a bit verbose even for professional developers. That's why I also wrote the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for DirectXMath which makes it work more like the classic math library you are looking for using XNA Game Studio like `Vector2`, `Vector3`, `Matrix` classes with 'C++ magic' covering up all the explicit loads & stores. SimpleMath types interop neatly with DirectXMath, so you can mix and match as you want.

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/introducing-directxmath/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMath) as well.

> DirectXMath is purposely an 'inline' library meaning in optimized code you shouldn't be passing variables much and instead just computing the value inside your larger function. The D3DXMath library in the [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-) `D3DX9`, `D3DX10`, `D3DX11` library is more old-school which relies on function-pointer tables and is heavily performance bound by the calling-convention overhead.
>
> These of course represent different engineering trade-offs. D3DXMath was able to do more substitution at runtime of specialized processor code paths, but pays for this flexibility with the calling-convention and indirection overhead. DirectXMath, on the other hand, assumes a SIMD baseline of SSE/SSE2 (or AVX on Xbox One) so you avoid the need for runtime detection or indirection and instead aggressively utilize inlining.